# Can Quantum Energy Teleportation theoretically be used for interstellar travel?

Tags: energy, quantum-entanglement, quantum-teleportation, interstellar-travel

I see that, recently, Quantum Energy Teleportation has become real physics: https://www.quantamagazine.org/physicists-use-quantum-mechanics-to-pull-energy-out-of-nothing-20230222/
Could this be theoretically used for some distant future energy source for interstellar travel?

Comment: I don't consider this the same as the question about dark energy, since the latter may not be related to vacuum energy or the ground state energy of a quantum field.

Answer (score 0):

As per usual, the details are in the fine print.  The basic theory of quantum teleportation has been around for about 30 years.  Its abilities for distant transmission of random information are well known.  However, the technique cannot be used without a classical information channel - i.e. something transmitted at light speed or less.  Typically the quantum information being teleported is a spin state.  (And obviously, the mere transmission of *random* data - even at speeds exceeding c - is in itself of little use.)

The cited article describes a novel process that is much the same. Energy can be "transferred" if you want to use that term.  However, the direction of energy transfer itself is random.  It may go from Alice to Bob, or from Bob to Alice.  Regardless of direction, no net energy is produced and there is strict conservation of energy.  And in those cases in which Bob is able to gain energy, it takes a classical signal to point that out to Bob.

I might suggest that simply sending a series of very energetic laser pulses from Alice to Bob would be a more effective manner to transfer energy.  Not that this technique would be useful with current technology.  (Otherwise we could do away with electric transmission towers.)